# How to hide a programmatically added html element with a css media query?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

After my view got initialized, I add a button to my google maps area by using javascript:

```
let centerControlDiv: any = document.createElement('div');
centerControlDiv.className = 'collapseButton'; //trying to hide it by css
let controlUI = document.createElement('div');
centerControlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

this.controlText = document.createElement('button');
this.controlText.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
controlUI.appendChild(this.controlText);

map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(centerControlDiv);
```

However, I want to show the button only on small screens. Therefore I added the following media queries:

```
  @media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .collapseButton {
      display: block  !important;
    }
    /* show it on small screens */
  }

  @media (min-width: 993px) {
    .collapseButton {
      display: none  !important;
    }
    /* hide it elsewhere */
  }
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. If I do:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("collapseButton")[0].style.display = 'none';
```

the button hides successfully.
What am I missing?

UPDATE: here is the DOM snipped including the button:
[image]

Comment: It's amsuing to downvote someone's answer without mentioning what is actually wrong with it or giving a feedback lol. But yeah whoever downvoted, if you know the solution, go ahead and do post it.

Comment: Is the map placed inside an `<ìframe>`?

Comment: no, it's an angular directive.

Comment: Is it adding a `style` attribute to your `.collapseButton`, in the final markup, containing a value for `display`?

Comment: The simple answer is, in this particular case, because you need to override JavaScript, you need to use `!important` for your rules. If that still doesn't work, you're probably having an error in your CSS file that prevents it from parsing as you expect it to.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't resolve the issue. Updated the question.

Comment: @AdrianKrebs Did you take that screenshot when your viewport was below 992 px?

Comment: Consider adding a live snippet ([mcve]), linking all required resources to reproduce the issue here. Without it, there's not much anyone can do. From what you provided the cause is not deductible. My guess is you have an error in your CSS and your code just doesn't apply. This is easily verifiable by inspecting the element and seeing what rules apply to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  /deep/.collapseButton {
    display: block;
  }
  /* show it on small screens */
}

@media (min-width: 993px) {
  /deep/.collapseButton {
    display: none;
  }
  /* hide it elsewhere */
}
```

Adding `/deep/` made it work. Still not sure why I had to add this. Any explanations appreciated.